# Getting error "Access restriction: The type 'Ignore' is not API"

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

Here is the long version

```
Access restriction: The type 'Ignore' is not API (restriction on required library 'C:\Program Files\Eclipse\plugins\org.junit_4.11.0.v201303080030\junit.jar')
```

I also get the same thing when trying to call on assertEquals and Test within JUnit for when I am trying to create my test class for a project I am working on for school.

I had to copy and paste the code from one school computer to another, so that leads me to think it is something going wrong with Eclipse. I also just started adding exceptions into the code and the test, and that was when I started to notice it.

Any advice on what to do? Wanted to try to solve this on my own before waiting till Monday when I can get help from the professor or the system admin.

Here are my imports

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Ignore;
import org.junit.Test;
```

Comment: What do your imports look like? And how did you add JUnit to your project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure in your Project Properties dialog, under Java Build Path in the  libraries tab, that you have JUnit 4 selected, (not 3)

Comment: This worked, I removed the JUnit 3 library and added the JUnit 4 to the build path. Thank you.